# How to get the date format of different Columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

In my pandas dataframe I have 2 to 3 different DateTime columns. Now I want to show the format of that date columns

Example:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2016-03-12 23:24:05 | 26-03-2016 11:23:09 AM |

Now it should print the format : YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS for Column1 and DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS AM for Column2

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of anything that parses the datetime formats, also strftime and strptime dosnot have the formats you show. You would have to rely on the [default formats](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) and using them you have to create all possible formats and your expected value in a dictionary. Then you can do below:

```
formats={'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S':'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS',
         '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S AM':'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS AM'}

possibilities = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((df.columns,formats.keys()))

u = df.astype(str) #if the datetime columns are not strings already
d = {}
for i in possibilities:
    try:
        pd.to_datetime(u[i[0]],format=i[1])
        d[i[0]] = formats.get(i[1])
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

---

```
print(d)

{'Column1': 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS', 'Column2': 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS AM'}
```